# How to prevent WebStorm/prettier from inserting randomly a space string in curly braces {" "} in .jsx?

Tags: jsx, phpstorm, webstorm

When autoformatting `.jsx` with prettier, I get random `{" "}` inserted.
As far as I can track this down, it happens when there is some empty space between `jsx` elements, and the trailing element is moved to a new line by the autoformatter.

e.g. this:

[image]

is autoformatted to this:

[image]

But if the trailing element is already on the next line, then the space between the elements gets removed. Which is the right behavior in my opinion.

Is it possible to turn the `{" "}` - insertion off?

Comment: can't reproduce; can you repeat the issue in a new project? do you use Prettier as a default formatter, or use IDE own formatter? `.jsx` file it can be repeated with would be helpful

Comment: @lena indeed it appears only with prettier. So it is probably not WebStorm at all.
I tried it with an empty project, only one `.jsx` file and a global prettier instance.

Comment: Indeed, I was able to reproduce the issue when running ` prettier --write src/components/MyComponent.js` in terminal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will face the same issue when formatting your code with Prettier in command line. this is by design, please see https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/4223#issuecomment-380093772 for explanation:

With jsx, trailing and leading whitespace on a line is removed on rendering:

```
<span>
    a
        <strong>tag</strong>
</span
```

becomes "atag".

You have to add `{" "}` if you want the space to show up, if the space is at the end or beginning of the line.

The only way to avoid the explicit space is to not have leading/trailing whitespace, and instead keep all of the whitespace that needs to be kept between the tags on any given line:

```
<span>
    a <strong>tag</strong>
</span
```

That will produce "a tag", just like the HTML one.